# Como manter zero a esquerda em importação no Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Olá
Tenho vários arquivos TXT com números de CPFs. O CPF tem 11 números, então pode ter zeros à esquerda para completar esse tamanho
Abri esses arquivos em Excel e os reuni em um só. Na coluna do CPF, antes de abrir cada arquivo, transformei no comando de importação do Excel para como Texto para manter os zeros. No formato xlsx deu certo

Mas quando gravei como CSV vi que os zeros da esquerda sumiram

Em Python 3 abri, para usar pandas depois, e vi que realmente perdeu o zero na esquerda e virou int64:

```
candidatos = pd.read_csv("candidatos_excel_cpfinteiro_csv.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1')

candidatos.info()

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 26245 entries, 0 to 26244
Data columns (total 9 columns):
UF                  26245 non-null object
Estado              26245 non-null object
Cargo               26245 non-null object
Nome_completo       26245 non-null object
CPF                 26245 non-null int64
Nome_urna           26245 non-null object
Partido             26245 non-null object
Partido_completo    26245 non-null object
Situacao            26245 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 1.0+ MB
```

Tentei abrir direto o arquivo de Excel, com o xlrd, mas ficou como número da mesma forma:

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('candidatos_excel_cpfinteiro.xlsx')

candidatos = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Planilha1')

candidatos.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 26245 entries, 0 to 26244
Data columns (total 9 columns):
UF                  26245 non-null object
Estado              26245 non-null object
Cargo               26245 non-null object
Nome_completo       26245 non-null object
CPF                 26245 non-null int64
Nome_urna           26245 non-null object
Partido             26245 non-null object
Partido_completo    26245 non-null object
Situacao            26245 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 1.0+ MB
```

Por favor, alguém teria uma sugestão de como manter os zeros à esquerda? Ou manter como string essa coluna?

Comment: como os cpfs estão dentro do arquivo .csv? Pelo que entendi da pergunta, o excel já exporta eles sem os zeros.

Comment: Olá, obrigado. Estão sempre com 11 digítos ("99493713415", "02376606446", "16436105468", "02108363262"...). Sim, quando gravo como CSV ele perde o zero à esquerda

Comment: Olá, acho que expliquei errado. No TXT original está com 11 dígitos  ("99493713415", "02376606446", "16436105468", "02108363262"...). Mas quando transformo em CSV no Excel aí perde o zero à esquerda

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como ler um arquivo csv pelo pandas sem apagar o primeiro numero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/508239/como-ler-um-arquivo-csv-pelo-pandas-sem-apagar-o-primeiro-numero)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode definir o `dtype` no momento da importação. Por exemplo:

```
candidatos = pd.read_csv("candidatos_excel_cpfinteiro_csv.csv",sep=';',
                         encoding = 'latin_1', dtype=str)
```

Também é possível definir o `dtype` individualmente, por exemplo, `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}`.

Para maiores detalhes, recomendo a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta importar direto do excel, usa essa linha de código que você não vai perder nenhum valor:

```
import pandas as pd

seu_dataframe = pd.read_excel('nome do seu arquivo .xlsx')
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não funcionou. Também corta o zero a esquerda quando importo como você indicou acima: a coluna fica assim - CPF                 26245 non-null int64

Comment: Mas no arquivo do excel está com o zero à esquerda e a coluna formatada como texto

Answer (score -2):

*Solução*

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\base\ATENDIMENTO_reduzido.txt", delimiter=',', encoding='latin-1', `dtype=str`)
```

[image: Print da Solução]

Comment: Veja [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/137387). Existem sandboxes online aos montes, veja sites como https://ideone.com/, https://replit.com/, https://research.google.com/colaboratory/,... onde pode criar, testar e compartilhar links para código fonte escritos em Python e em várias outras linguagens. No site https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/index.html você encontra a documentação Python para usar como referência. No site https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/ você encontra a documentação Pandas para usar como referência.

Comment: Veja um exemplo de como seria uma [resposta a uma pergunta similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/508243/137387). Aproveite e veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].