# Como ler um arquivo csv pelo pandas sem apagar o primeiro numero?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Tenho um arquivo.csv e quero ler com a biblioteca pandas em Python. Quando executo o comando ele tira o primeiro 0 da sequencia de números.
Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?
Eu quero que ele mantenha os zeros na frente igual do arquivo.csv

```
import pandas as pd
lista=pd.read_csv('~/caminho/meu_arquivo.csv')


#Esse é meu arquivo csv
"""
teste
01234567899
12345678909
23456789012
09876543211
"""
#Minha saída
"""
Out[98]: 
     teste
0   1234567899
1  12345678909
2  23456789012
3   9876543211
```

https://replit.com/@Dennisrochaa/teste-1#main.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arquivos [*CSV*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) não vem com definição dos tipos de dados de suas colunas. Então o módulo [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) ao ler um *CSV* deve inferir qual o tipo de dados mais adequado.

No seu caso a coluna teste foi avaliada como uma coluna numérica. Em tipos de dados numéricos os zeros a esquerda são automaticamente suprimidos.
Especifique explicitamente através do parâmetro `dtype` do método [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) que a coluna é uma string.

O parâmetro `dtype` pode ser preenchido com um dicionário e onde as chaves são os nomes das colunas e o valores os respectivos tipos de dados:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = pd.read_csv('./meu_arquivo.csv', dtype={"teste": str})
print(lista)
```

```
         teste
0  01234567899
1  12345678909
2  23456789012
3  09876543211
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Rep.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/dtype#main.py)</sup>

Também `dtype` pode ser preenchido com um único tipo de dados onde será aplicado em todas as colunas:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = pd.read_csv('./meu_arquivo.csv', dtype=str)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Muuito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente como eu estava esperando

Comment: @rochaa, Não agradeça veja: [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)