# O comando to_csv() está salvando uma coluna int em double no meu csv

Tags: python, pandas, spark

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu df no pyspark (resultado)

Quando eu uso:

`(file_name_out="TB_CAMPAIGN_Avon"  path_out="/home/257615628/trusted_to_refined"  resultado.toPandas().to_csv(f'{path_out}/{file_name_out}.csv',header = 'true', sep="|")`

Meu output do cvs:
[image: Eu não entendo porque o pandas adiciona ".0"]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como ler um arquivo csv pelo pandas sem apagar o primeiro numero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/508239/como-ler-um-arquivo-csv-pelo-pandas-sem-apagar-o-primeiro-numero)

Answer (score -4):

tente fazer isto:

df['coluna com double'] = pd.to_numeric(df['coluna com double'], downcast='signed')

ou

df['coluna com double'] = pd.to_numeric(df['coluna com double'], downcast='int')

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).